# Visual Studio doesn't break on assert violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, assert, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging a CMake target in Visual Studio 2019 for a project which is managed by CMake and built using MinGW.

However, when an assertion fails the debugger simply quits without giving me a call stack or letting me inspect the current state of the program. (Normal breakpoints do suspend execution as expected.)

[image: breakpoints_work]

I've enabled Break When Thrown for all C++ Exceptions in `Debug > Windows > Exception Settings`, but to no avail.

How can I make Visual Studio break execution when an assertion fails?

Comment: `assert` is a C function and does not throw any C++ exceptions. You should see an "assertion failed" message, though.

Comment: There is no category "C Exceptions" in `Debug > Windows > Exceptions`

Comment: Are you sure you are building the "Debug" configuration, and running with an attached debuger?

Comment: I am seeing an assertion failed message, but the execution doesn't stop to let me inspect variables at the moment the assertion failure happens.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes; a normal breakpoint works as expected.

Comment: @TimKuipers A normal breakpoint can still work for non-Debug builds, specially on a `std::cerr` which has a low chance of being optimized out.

Comment: I think it will not much difference if you enable or not all the exceptions. Assertions are not exceptions. You can't recover from them.

Comment: When msvc is the compiler in Visual Studio Community, Pro or Enterprise you will get a dialog prompt on an assert failed. I am not sure about mingw.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My CMakeCache has `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug` and only has `-DNDEBUG` for the other release types.

Comment: Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configure-cmake-debugging-sessions?view=msvc-160#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20start%20a,based%20on%20your%20active%20configuration.).

Answer (score 2):

If your project is a "Console" application rather than a "Windows" application and you have used <assert.h> then according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert?view=msvc-160):

> The destination of the diagnostic message depends on the type of
> application that called the routine. Console applications receive the
> message through stderr. In a Windows-based application, assert calls
> the Windows MessageBox function to create a message box to display the
> message with three buttons: Abort, Retry, and Ignore

So a possible solution is to temporarily build your program as a ["Windows" app](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE) by adding the WIN32 option to your executable definition:

```
add_executable(<name> WIN32 [source1] [source2 ...])
```

Comment: This is particularly annoying when the failed assertion comes from a library (e.g. Boost) and all you get is the line number in the library and no stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the NDEBUG macro is enabled in your project and that stops VS from breaking on assertion failure.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)

> If NDEBUG is defined as a macro name at the point in the source code
> where  is included, then assert does nothing.
>
> If NDEBUG is not defined, then assert checks if its argument (which
> must have scalar type) compares equal to zero. If it does, assert
> outputs implementation-specific diagnostic information on the standard
> error output and calls std::abort. The diagnostic information is
> required to include the text of expression, as well as the values of
> the standard macros **FILE**, **LINE**, and the standard variable
> **func** (since C++11).

Comment: My CMakeCache has `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug` and only has `-DNDEBUG` for the other release types.